# pzc font family not displaying when compiled with LuaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex

Consider the following example code. I'm using TeX Live 2019 (`2019.20190710-1`) with Debian 10 (buster).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Faheem Mitha}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address}
\renewcommand{\mobilephonename}{Mobile}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{Phone number}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{Email address}
\setkomavar{signature}{(\usekomavar{fromname})}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
    {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont
      \hspace{\textwidth}
      \usekomavar{fromname}\\
      \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
      \usekomavar*{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\\
      \usekomavar*{emailseparator}\usekomavar{emailseparator}\usekomavar{fromemail}
    }
  }%
}

\def\today{xxth xxxxxxx, 201x}
\begin{letter}{To Address}

  \opening{Addressee}

  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The header, which is set in the pzc font family, does not display when using LuaTeX, though it works in PDFLaTeX.

This is the message with LuaTeX.

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TU+pzc on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file TUpzc.fd. on input line 28.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/pzc/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 28.
```

And here is the corresponding message with PDFLaTeX.

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+pzc on input line 27.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1pzc.fd
File: ot1pzc.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/pzc.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/pzc/m/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/pzc/mb/it' tried instead on input line 27.
```

Comment: do not use such legacy 8bit font family names with luatex, use the fontspec package and use a Unicode OpenType font

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. Do you have a specific recommendation?

Comment: TeX Gyre Chorus would be a suitable Zapf Chancery clone

Comment: use `\usefont{T1}{pzc}{m}{n}` instead of only `\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use such legacy 8bit font family names with luatex, use the `fontspec` package and use a Unicode OpenType font

TeX Gyre Chorus would be a suitable Zapf Chancery clone.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Faheem Mitha}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address}
\renewcommand{\mobilephonename}{Mobile}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{Phone number}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{Email address}
\setkomavar{signature}{(\usekomavar{fromname})}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
    {\fontspec{TeX Gyre Chorus}
      \hspace{\textwidth}
      \usekomavar{fromname}\\
      \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
      \usekomavar*{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\\
      \usekomavar*{emailseparator}\usekomavar{emailseparator}\usekomavar{fromemail}
    }
  }%
}

\def\today{xxth xxxxxxx, 201x}
\begin{letter}{To Address}

  \opening{Addressee}

  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. So `\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont` is replaced by `\fontspec{TeX Gyre Chorus}`?